If the subgroup $(B, C)$ normalizes $A$, the subgroup $(A, (B, C))$ is generated by the elements $(a, (b, c))$

If the subgroup $(B, C)$ normalizes $A$, the subgroup $(A, (B, C))$ is generated by the elements $(a, (b, c))$

(This is a proposition stated in Bourbaki's Algebra.)

Firstly let me explain the notion I use here:
$$(a,b) = a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$$
and $(A,B)$ is the subgroup generated by the commutators of $A$ and $B$.

Now I guess it's not a true proposition: I think only by $(a,(b,c))$ could not generate $(A, (B, C))$.
The key idea of the original proof in the book is to utilize the following formula:
$$(a,bc) = (a,c)(c,(b,a))(a,b)$$
Now taking $(a,(b,c)x) = (a,x)(x,((b,c),a))(a,(b,c))$
By induction you can see the commutator of $a\in A$ and a multiplication of form $(b,c)$ is generated with $(a,(b,c))$
And then the book assert the proposition to be true.
Yet I really think this is  not enough: apparently $(a,(c,b))$ is also contained in $(A,(B,C))$, but this proof just skips it.
So is this a true proposition? Or shall I add $(a,(c,b))$ as another generator?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

What does the notation $(B,C)$ mean?

@VincentBatens I am almost certain this is meant to be (group) commutators. And given the right-normed convention, I'm going to hazard a guess that $(x,y)$ stands for $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$; and that for subgroups $B$ and $C$, $(B,C)$ is the subgroup generated by all $(b,c)$ with $b\in B$ and $c\in C$. Using parentheses rather than brackets was not uncommon for a while, and of course Bourbaki can be a bit idiosyncratic in any case.

Please include the actual question in your post (not just the title line; posts don't begin in the title line); and your commutator convention (there are two, and while they are essentially interchangeable, the precise formulas will be slightly different).

... actually, the given product formula only works if $(x,y) = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$.

My bad. I'm new to MSE so I don't know the convention. Sorry.

From your product formula, it appears that you are using the convention
$$(x,y) = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy.$$
Note that $(x,y)^{-1}=(y,x)$. So $(a,(c,b)) = (a,(b,c)^{-1})$. Also,
$$(x,y^{-1}) = y(y,x)y^{-1}.$$
Indeed, we have
$$y(y,x)y^{-1} = yy^{-1}x^{-1}yxy^{-1} = x^{-1}yxy^{-1}=(x,y^{-1}).$$
So
$$(a,(c,b)) = (a,(b,c)^{-1}) = (b,c)((b,c),a)(b,c)^{-1}.$$
But $a(x,y)a^{-1} = (axa^{-1},aya^{-1})$, so
$$(a,(c,b)) = (b,c)((b,c),a)(b,c)^{-1} = ((b,c)^{(b,c)},a^{(b,c)}).$$
Since $(B,C)$ normalizes $A$, then $a^{(b,c)}=a'$ for some $a'\in A$, so
$$(a,(c,b)) = ((b,c),a^{(b,c)}) = ((b,c),a') = (a',(b,c))^{-1}.$$
Thus, if you have all generators of the form $(a,(b,c))$, then you automatically get all generators of the form $(a,(c,b))$ as well.

Ah thanks a lot

@Sinnaruil if this fully answers your question, be sure to accept the answer so your question doesn't show as "unanswered."
